# cpulimit, but for load? Pause a command until load avg goes below some figure?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-interface, load-average

The programme `cpulimit` on Linux is great. You can tell it to limit a process so that it doesn't use more than X% of the CPU. For example, I know someone who's laptop overheats if the CPU runs too hot for too long. When doing some video encoding, they use cpulimit to prevent the CPU being fully used, and hence overheating. You can't use `nice` to stop that.

Is there something like that for the *load*?

Ideally I'd like to be able to do `loadlimit 4 my-command-here` and it will start `my-command-here` and every X sec `loadlimit` will check the (1 minute) load of the machine, and if it's above 4, then `my-command-here` will be paused. When the load goes below 4, the command will be paused. This is exactly what `cpulimit` does BTW.

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: Can you fix the root cause of your load issues?

Comment: System load average and CPU utilization are two completely different things, so I don't see how what you want is "exactly what cpulimit does". System load average (as reported e.g. by uptime on GNU) is simply the number of processes in a runnable or running state, plus on Linux also those in noninterruptible sleep. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)#Unix-style_load_calculation and [man 3 getloadavg](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getloadavg).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I know load is different from CPU. When I said "the same as cpulimit" I meant "monitor the load, and then pause this process until the load gets below X"

Comment: @ewwhite In /this/ case the load is caused by me `rm -rf` on a massive directory structure, which degrades my desktop's performance. In /this/ case, I want to do a "slow" rm -rf so that I can delete the directory without affecting my desktop performance.

Comment: Not an answer because not enough time, but cgroups can do this, if you combine it with the freeze provider.

Answer (score 1):

With what you describe in the comments, it would seem that your actual problem could be solved by `ionice`.

```
ionice -c 3 -p <pid>
```

where `-p <pid>` is the pid of process you want to reschedule and `-c 3` puts it into the `idle` class so it only gets disk time if no one else wants it. On a busy system, that can make the process in question slow, so you could experiment with different values for the priority in a higher class, e.g.

```
ionice -c 2 -n 6 -p <pid>
```

Read `man ionice` for more details.

The problem with your proposed `loadlimit` would be that a high load can be caused by very different things and slowing one process wouldn't necessarily impact the load at all.

Comment: Although `ionice rm -rf ..` does seem to help a little, it still increases my load and I can see some general slowdown.